# Почему редюсеры подключенные так StoreModule.forFeature(reducer, authorReducer),работает только нижний?

Tags: angular, angular10

Пытаюсь в модуль подключить редюсеры с другого модуля, делаю это таким способом, но работает только редюсер который подключен последний, а остальные не работают, почему?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AdminComponent, ListClientComponent, EditUserComponent, ListPrintingEditionComponent, UpdatePrintingEditionComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AdminRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature(reducers.reducer, reducers.adminReducers),
    StoreModule.forFeature(reducer, authorReducer),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([ClientListEffect, DeleteEffect, BlockEffect, 
                              UpdateEffect, PrintingEditionListEffect, PrintingEditionListEffect,
                              DeletePrintingEditionEffect, UpdatePrintingEditionEffect, ListAuthorsEffect]),
    
    PipesModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatSlideToggleModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
   
  ]
})
export class AdminModule { }
```

Comment: так ангуляр2 4 8 10? Какой?)

Comment: @Lofectr 10, просто написал всех что б больше людей охватить